# Clear Concept of Couchbase lite vs Couchbase Server

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-lite

I am new at couchbase lite. I have studied couchbase Server.
I just want to know , 
what is is couchbase lite in simple words ?
Is it possible to use it on windows application?
Is there Different console than Couchbase server?(means whr should exactly i see the stored data by couchbase lite .like for couchbase server http://localhost:8091/ui/index.html#/overview )
What is relation between couchbase server and couchbase lite????

(I knw questions are silly but need to clear the basics )

please help me out !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couchbase Lite is a lightweight mobile/embedded nosql database and is part of [Couchbase Mobile](http://www.couchbase.com/nosql-databases/couchbase-mobile). It is designed to be on a mobile device, embedded device, OS, etc. So yes, it can be part of a Windows application and communicate Couchbase Mobile.

Couchbase Mobile is made up of Couchbase Lite, Sync_Gateway and Couchbase Server. Couchbase Sync_Gateway is the app server Couchbase Lite talks to in order to synchronize data between devices and Couchbase Server. [Couchbase Server](http://www.couchbase.com/nosql-databases/couchbase-server) is a full featured operational NoSQL Database that is a fully distributed and clustered system.

I could get into more detail, but that really is not what StackOverflow is for as it is not coding related per se. I recommend you go to the Couchbase Forums.

Comment: Thanx..it helped alot :)

Comment: @Shriram mark this answer as an accepted answer if it helped you out! It helps keep SO clean, and shows appreciation for the effort put in to help out.